# Can't set the cookies in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, cookies, puppeteer

After saving some scraped cookies in a JSON, i want to restore them in a new Session. 
The cookie Objects seem to load fine.

```js
async function injectCookies(page) {
    let data = await fs.promises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, process.env.COOKIE_FILE), { encoding: "UTF-8" });

    if (data) {
        try {
            console.log('setting cookies');

            //JSON.parse(data)[0] returns a Cookie-Object
            await page.setCookie(...JSON.parse(data)); 

            console.log(await page.cookies()); //Yields []

            return Promise.resolve();
        } catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof SyntaxError) {
                console.log('cookies.json > JSON corrupt');
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MainFunction:

```js
async function start() {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch(browserConfig);
    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await injectCookies(page);

    // await page.goto("https://www.google.com");

    await saveCookies(page);
}
```

(saveCookies uses page.cookies() and JSON.stringify())

The logged cookies before trying to set them:

```
[ { name: '1P_JAR',
    value: '2019-08-25-20',
    domain: '.google.com',
    path: '/',
    expires: 1569356838.739606,
    size: 19,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    session: false },
  { name: 'CONSENT',
    value: 'WP.27d849',
    domain: '.google.com',
    path: '/',
    expires: 2145916800.363398,
    size: 16,
    httpOnly: false,
    secure: false,
    session: false }]
```

Comment: For some reason chromium won't set google cookies. I switched to playwright + webkit and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

[Puppeteer doc](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pagecookiesurls) said about await page.cookies([...urls]).

> If no URLs are specified, this method returns cookies for the current
>   page URL. If URLs are specified, only cookies for those URLs are
>   returned.

You need to open a page the first. Because with `await page.cookies()` you get cookies for current page URLs. There is no page open in your case, so you got empty cookies array.

Update your Main function to, it might help.

```
async function start() {
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch(browserConfig);
    let page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://www.google.com");

    await injectCookies(page);

    await saveCookies(page);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I already visited google.com and saved the cookies that are listed above. But if i try to set them before visiting a page, they wont get set (=> console.log(await page.cookies()); //Yields [])